# Combining two dataframes with same columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a form that is filled in by multiple researchers.
I now have (say) two forms that i want to join.

Form one:

```
site   value1   Value2 
1      A          B
2      B          C 
3      NA         NA
4      NA         NA
5      A          NA
```

Form two

```
site   value1   value2 
1      NA         NA
2      NA         NA  
3      A          A
4      B          B
5      NA         NA
```

expected output:

```
site   value1   value2 
1      A          B
2      B          B 
3      A          A
4      B          B
5      A          NA
```

I tried using the `dplyr` package to try and join, but this does almost the same as `dplyr::bind_cols`.

I prefer solving this within the `tidyverse`. Help much appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the missing values are `NA`, then `coalesce` would be easier.  Here, we assume that the 'site' values are the same and are in the same order in both datasets

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('value'), ~ 
               coalesce(., df2[[cur_column()]])))
```

-output

```
#   site value1 value2
#1    1      A      B
#2    2      B      C
#3    3      A      A
#4    4      B      B
#5    5      A   <NA>
```

---

If the datasets have difference in 'site', then do a `left` join and `coalesce` between the `.x` and `.y` columns.  The logic is to loop `across` those columns that have `.x` suffix in their names, within the loop, retrieve the column name (`cur_column()`), replace the suffix with `.y`, `get` the value of that column and do the `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = 'site') %>%
    mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~ 
               coalesce(., get(str_replace(cur_column(), '\\.x$', '\\.y'))))) %>%
    select(-ends_with('.y')) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_remove(., '\\.x'), ends_with('.x'))

#   site value1 value2
#1    1      A      B
#2    2      B      C
#3    3      A      A
#4    4      B      B
#5    5      A   <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(site = 1:5, value1 = c("A", "B", NA, NA, "A"), 
    value2 = c("B", "C", NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df2 <- structure(list(site = 1:5, value1 = c(NA, NA, "A", "B", NA), 
    value2 = c(NA, NA, "A", "B", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: How does this know to link by Site, or is it just positional right now?

Comment: Hi Akrun, thanks for your lightning fast response! I will look into the coalesce function. 
I also edited my OP since i have multiple columns in the form. Is your method easy to adjust for this?

Comment: @Stevestingray in your example one of the column starts with uppercase.  Is that a tyypo

Answer (score 1):

We can use {powerjoin}

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "site", conflict = coalesce_xy)
#>   site value1 value2
#> 1    1      A      B
#> 2    2      B      C
#> 3    3      A      A
#> 4    4      B      B
#> 5    5      A   <NA>
```